# How to enable automatic translation updates in the browser with i18next and Vite?

Tags: reactjs, vite, i18next

I'm working on a React with Vite and Typescript project that uses i18next for localization. Whenever I make changes or add keys to the i18next localization files, I have to manually refresh the browser to see the updated translations.

Is there a way to enable automatic translation updates in the browser upon saving the localization files, eliminating the need to reload the page manually?

Thanks!